# Write to specific place in XML

Tags: c#

I have a xml soap file and I need to put a value between two nodes :

```
<testedObject></testedObject> 
<lsp></lsp>
```

I have some problems with colons and access to those above elements. The XML:

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP:Header>
    <header xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
        <security>
            <user>myusername</user> 
            <password>mypassword</password> 
        </security>
    </header>
    </SOAP:Header>
<SOAP:Body>
<sas.Test.adhocExecuteAndWait xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
<deployer>mydeployer</deployer>
<synchronousDeploy>true</synchronousDeploy>
            <testedObject></testedObject> 
                <test>
                    <mpls.LspPing>
                        <actionMask>
                            <bit>create</bit> 
                        </actionMask>
                    <testTargetType>lsp</testTargetType> 
                    <lsp></lsp> 
                    <packetsToSend>45</packetsToSend>           
                    <displayedName></displayedName> 
                    </mpls.LspPing>
                </test>

            <timeout>300000</timeout> 
            <keepTest>true</keepTest>
</sas.Test.adhocExecuteAndWait>
</SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

What I did so far is:

```
  XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(@"C:\file.xml");

    XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("SOAP:Envelope[@*]");
    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {
        XmlNode anode = xn.SelectSingleNode("SOAP:Body");
        foreach (XmlNode item in anode)
        {
            XmlNode example = item.SelectSingleNode("sas.Test.adhocExecuteAndWait[@*]");
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {

            }
        }

    }
```

I have problems with colons and to be honest I am stuck on it. Could you take a look?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't using XElement?

Comment: if you are sure you'll have this structure, you could find the `lsp`  node with xpath: `var x = item.SelectSingleNode("sas.Test.adhocExecuteAndWait[@*]\test\lsp")` then call `InsertBefore` on the `test` element like so: `item.SelectSingleNode("sas.Test.adhocExecuteAndWait[@*]\test").InsertBefore(<your new element>, x);`

Comment: something wrong with your statment could you tell me where i should put this code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to make the output look like this:

```
            <testedObject>John</testedObject> 
            <test>
                <mpls.LspPing>
                    <actionMask>
                        <bit>create</bit> 
                    </actionMask>
                <testTargetType>lsp</testTargetType> 
                <lsp>John</lsp> 
                <packetsToSend>45</packetsToSend>           
                <displayedName></displayedName> 
                </mpls.LspPing>
            </test>
```

Then I would do something like this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(@"C:\file.xml");
//create a namespace manager for the SOAP Namespace
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("SOAP", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");

//create a new node
XmlNode newNode = xml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, "John", "");
newNode.Value = "John"; 

//get the elements where do you want to add the new node
XmlNode testedObject = xml.SelectSingleNode("//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'testedObject')]", ns);

XmlNode lspNode = xml.SelectSingleNode("//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'lsp')]", ns);

//add the new node
testedObject.AppendChild(newNode.Clone());
lspNode.AppendChild(newNode.Clone());
```

**EDIT**

The greater lesson here is how to deal with blank namespaces. Click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950779.aspx) for reference. 
one way to improve this is to use `local-name()='nodename'` instead of `starts-with`.

Comment: No exactly, what i want is to put some value lets say: "John" between already existing nodes: <testedObject></testedObject> and <lsp></lsp> so what i should see is: <testedObject>John</testedObject>   and <lsp>John</lsp>

Comment: Changed the example in answer.

Comment: i got two errors:
The name 'xmlCreateNode' does not exist in the current context
The name 'parent' does not exist in the current context
EDIT:
I corrected:
xmlcreatenode -> xml.CreateNode
parent -> xml

anyway i am getting the error:
Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function. 
on this line:
XmlNode testedObject = xml.SelectSingleNode("SOAP:Envelope[@*]/SOAP:Body/sas.Test.adhocExecuteAndWait[@*]/testedObject");

Comment: missed a dot for the first one, added an `XmlNamespaceManager`

Comment: error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on line:  testedObject.AppendChild(newNode);

Comment: this is due to an incorrect xpath query. i changed it to the descendant notation.

Comment: i would like to chat but i have no enough reputation points to join. Sorry. Anyway i am receiving same error could you check please?

Comment: finally figured out how to get past the blank namespace

Comment: There is no error now, but after save document there is nothing new i mean value was not pas to those nodes.

Comment: I just updated the answer to fix that problem. Try now.

Comment: great it works !! many thanks !! could you tell me lets assume i got second <lsp></lsp> in the xml file how i could set the value for it? And the second question how to set some value for <timestamp></timestamp> ?

Comment: If there is a list of nodes to update, use `SelectNodes`, if you want to set another element text, you'd do it similarly what is done in the answer.